# VS Code MDX Extension shows error for footnotes and default export

Tags: reactjs, next.js, markdown, vscode-extensions, mdx

I have project on Next.js with Tailwind CSS and I am using MDX for some of my pages. Inside MDX file there is this export line:

```
export default ({children}) => <div className='prose'>{children}</div>
```

This line shows this error: **A module cannot have multiple default exports.ts(2528)**

In addition, I am using footnotes like this:

```
Mübalağa ve ziyade[^ziyade]lik manası...

[^ziyade]: ziyade: fazla, çok
```

and this line shows this error:

```
No link definition found: '^ziyade'(link.no-such-reference)
```

Until today there were no error like these. I have been trying to find a solution for hours but I could not.

I have tried to change .eslintrc.json settings following these instructions: [Fixing MDX linting errors in Next.js using eslint-plugin-mdx](https://www.interglobalmedianetwork.com/blog/fixing-mdx-linting-errors-in-nextjs-using-eslintpluginmdx), but did not work.

I have updated all packages and Next.js but did not work.

I am using VS Code MDX extension for syntax highlighting and I believe these errors are related to this extension. I have tried to change its settings as described in their page but it did not work either.

package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@mdx-js/loader": "^3.0.0",
    "@mdx-js/react": "^3.0.0",
    "@next/mdx": "^14.0.2",
    "rehype-slug": "^6.0.0",
    "remark-gfm": "^4.0.0",
  },
```

next.config.mjs

```
import remarkGfm from 'remark-gfm'
import rehypeSlug from 'rehype-slug';

import nextMDX from '@next/mdx'

const withMDX = nextMDX({
  extension: /\.mdx?$/,
  options: {
    remarkPlugins: [
      remarkGfm, // GitHub Flavored Markdown
    ],
    rehypePlugins: [
      rehypeSlug, // add IDs to any h1-h6 tag that doesn't have one, using a slug made from its text
    ],
  }
})

/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  output: 'export',
  trailingSlash: true,
  pageExtensions: ['js', 'jsx', 'ts', 'tsx', 'md', 'mdx'],
```

tsconfig.json

```
"mdx": {
   "plugins": ["remark-gfm"]
},
```

Is there a way to prevent these error? Thanks.

Comment: It seems to be an error related to 1.5.0. I have installed 1.4.0 and errors disappeared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error was caused by the version 1.5.0. I have removed that version and installed 1.4.0. Error disappeared.